# Virtual Table layout in memory?

Tags: c++, vtable

how are virtual tables stored in memory? their layout?

e.g.

```
class A{
    public:
         virtual void doSomeWork();
};

class B : public A{
    public:
         virtual void doSomeWork();
};
```

How will be the layout of virtual tables of class A and class B in memory?

Comment: Maybe you're concerned about memory model because you need to reuse some structs from a C library in your C++ program. For that you might want to look at this link: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/mixing-c-and-cpp.html

Comment: If you have some time, try to swallow that: [Itanium C++ ABI](https://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As others have said, this is compiler dependant, and not something that you ever really need to think about in day-to-day use of C++. However, if you are simply curious about the issue, you should read Stan Lippman's book [Inside the C++ Object Model](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Inside-Object-Model-Stanley-Lippman/dp/0201834545).

Answer (score 39):

For GCC compiler in Linux run:

```
g++ -fdump-lang-class example.h
```

> **NOTE**: Before GCC 8, the option is `-fdump-class-hierarchy` instead of `-fdump-lang-class`.

The output is:

```
Vtable for A
A::_ZTV1A: 3u entries
0     (int (*)(...))0
8     (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI1A)
16    (int (*)(...))A::doSomeWork

Class A
   size=8 align=8
   base size=8 base align=8
A (0x7fb76785a4e0) 0 nearly-empty
    vptr=((& A::_ZTV1A) + 16u)

Vtable for B
B::_ZTV1B: 3u entries
0     (int (*)(...))0
8     (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI1B)
16    (int (*)(...))B::doSomeWork

Class B
   size=8 align=8
   base size=8 base align=8
B (0x7fb7678510d0) 0 nearly-empty
    vptr=((& B::_ZTV1B) + 16u)
  A (0x7fb76785a540) 0 nearly-empty
      primary-for B (0x7fb7678510d0)
```

Also I've created the [vtable-dumper](https://github.com/lvc/vtable-dumper) tool to list contents of virtual tables in the shared objects. With this tool you don't need to compile headers, just run it on the object:

```
vtable-dumper SHLIB
```

Comment: Although this answer doesn't point out that the layout isn't standardised, it clearly is the best, since it shows a simple way to learn from a compiler, its model of object layout. Thanks!

Comment: BTW don't take `(int (*)(...))` literally, it's a placeholder type!

Answer (score 6):

vtable layout in memory is completely compiler dependent; there's no "correct" or universal approach taken.

Comment: how do standard compilers like gcc and visual studio store them?

Comment: Wikipedia ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table ) uses g++ as an example when describing vtable layout.

Answer (score 4):

As others already wrote, there is no general approach. (Heck, nobody even mandates that virtual tables are *used* at all.)

However, I believe they are most likely implemented as a hidden pointer at a certain offset in the object which references a table of function pointers. Certain virtual functions' addresses occupy certain offsets in that table. Usually there's also a pointer to the dynamic type's `std::type_info` object.

If you're interested in things like this, read [Lippmann's "Inside the C++ Object Model"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201834545). However, unless your interest is academic (or you're trying to write a C++ compiler -- but then you shouldn't need to ask), you shouldn't bother. It's an implementation detail you don't need to know and should never rely on.

Answer (score 3):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table):

> The C++ standards do not mandate
>   exactly how dynamic dispatch must be
>   implemented

So the answer is no. Layout of vtable  is implementation defined.

Comment: "The answer is no"? It wasn't a yes/no question.

Comment: I'd say, given "Virtual Table layout in memory?", this is open for different opinions. `:)`

Comment: "_Layout of vtable is implementation defined_" No. Many implementations do not define how the vtables are structured, and the standard doesn't say anything about vtables, not even that they have to exist. The standard doesn't even mention vtables, so they can't be "implementation defined".

Answer (score 1):

For a very detailed description of [Open Watcom](http://www.openwatcom.org)'s class layout have a look at the [Class Layout](http://perforce.openwatcom.org:4000/@md=d&cd=//depot/openwatcom/bld/plusplus/notes/&cdf=//depot/openwatcom/bld/plusplus/notes/layout.txt&c=JDq@//depot/openwatcom/bld/plusplus/notes/layout.txt?ac=64&rev1=1) notes